# How to tell clang-tidy to ignore some headers?

Tags: c++, warnings, compiler-warnings, clang-tidy

I have some C++ header files in a project that trigger clang-tidy warnings.
For various reasons I cannot edit those files (to fix the warnings or to `//NOLINT` them) at this time, but I would still like to suppress the warnings when compiling sources that include those files.

I tried to tell clang-tidy to treat the folder where those files are located as a system include folder, but for some reason it does not seem to prevent it from displaying the warnings:

```
$ clang-tidy --header-filter=".*" --extra-arg="-isystem /Users/me/work/server/framework/random" --extra-arg-before="--driver-mode=g++" rpp/finder.cpp

211720 warnings generated.
423440 warnings generated.
/Users/me/work/server/framework/random/scale.h:51:37: warning: forwarding reference parameter 'gen' is never forwarded inside the function body [cppcoreguidelines-missing-std-forward]
   51 | static Result downScale(Generator&& gen, Result range)
      |                                     ^
/Users/me/work/server/framework/random/shuffle.h:19:104: warning: forwarding reference parameter 'g' is never forwarded inside the function body [cppcoreguidelines-missing-std-forward]
   19 | void shuffle(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator sentinel, UniformRandomNumberGenerator&& g)
      |                                                                                                        ^
Suppressed 424918 warnings (423436 in non-user code, 1482 NOLINT).
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Clarification: I want clang-tidy to check all headers except for the ones located in that specific folder.  Thus the `-header-filter=.*`

I also tried wrapping the includes in

```
// NOLINTBEGIN
#include "framework/random/scale.h"
#include "framework/random/shuffle.h"
// NOLINTEND
```

But that didn't suppress the warnings either.

Comment: `Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers.` And you run `clang-tidy --system-headers=0 --header-filter=".*"`. Does not it look weird?

Comment: It didn't work without `--system-headers=0`, I added it as an attempted fix, I'll remove it from the example.

Comment: I try to rephrase if you can't understand the output. You don't want to display errors from headers. But you use `--header-filter=".*"` to display errors from headers. Does not it look weird?

Comment: I do want to display warnings from all headers except from headers in a specific directory.  That file (and others like it in the project) has multiple includes that I want to be checked.  Is it clearer now?  I can edit the question

Comment: Don't run clang-tidy with `--header-filter=".*` for rpp/finder.cpp. Run clang-tidy for desired header files additionally.

Comment: Can't do that.  `clang-tidy` is invoked by the `CMake`-generated script for that project.  I just extracted the command that `CMake` and `ninja` invoke, and removed everything unrelated.